# Css: set a div element 100% of its parent when its child is less then 100% height

Tags: html, css

I have a flex div that contains 2 elements. I want the 2 elements to be the parent height when their content should be auto height, but I always get the inner content height.

my code:

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<style>
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
    }
  .parent {
    background: gray;
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .child {
    height: 100%;
    background: blue;
    border: 1px solid white;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
      <div>
        <div>abc</div>
        <div>abc</div>
    </div>
    </div>
     <div class="child">
      <div>abc</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The second "child" div should also be the parent height, while its inner div should remain auto height. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `height: 100%`, try `align-self: stretch` on the `child` class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep the default alignment and to remove `height: 100%`, so the children are stretched by default.

Then set `display: flex` also for children with the desired alignment

```css
   html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
  }
  
  .parent {
    background: gray;
    display:flex;
  }
  
  .child {
    background: blue;
    border: 1px solid white;
    display: flex;
    align-items:center;
  }
```

```html
  
   <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
      <div>
        <div>abc</div>
        <div>abc</div>
    </div>
    </div>
     <div class="child">
      <div>abc</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a height to the `.parent` div, like: `height: 300px;` or `height: 100%;`

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}
.parent {
  background: gray;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 200px;
}
.child {
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
      <div>
        <div>abc</div>
        <div>abc</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      <div>abc</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```